# Proper use of DoEvents() that compatible with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Since VB6 I rarely use the method DoEvents() in C#.

I need to use the same function now for same purpose

I notice that people use this function ([Application.DoEvents Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents.aspx) ):

```
Application.DoEvents()
```

but this suits Windows Forms.

Now I'm working with WPF.

Is there a similar method in WPF?

Or maybe I shouldn't use this method anymore?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "for same purpose (not for UI)". Given that the whole point of Application.DoEvents *is* to process outstanding UI events, what are you trying to do with it?

Comment: My mistake. It is about UI after all. By reading your answer I realize that  its not usefull anymore. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or maybe I shouldn't use this method anymore?

This.

Basically, the use of `Application.DoEvents()` is almost always an indication that you've got a long-running task which *should* be executed on a different thread, calling back to the UI thread where UI access is required.

`Application.DoEvents()` is basically a hack people use when they don't want to take the time to do things properly - at least in the vast majority of cases.

There are various ways of writing long-running tasks which interact with the UI, depending on which versions of the language/framework you're using, and what your long-running task consists of. Options to consider:

- Explicitly creating a new thread
- Explicitly using the thread pool
- Using `BackgroundWorker`
- Using the Task Parallel Library (TPL) - requires .NET 4+
- Using asynchronous APIs, which is *much* simpler as of .NET 4.5 / C# 5